# Bash script to find placeholders in file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to find all placeholders in a file.

**For example**

I have following file:

```
<property name="sdfasdf" value="$ABC.D"></property>
<property name="sadf" value="$DFG.F.G"></property>
<property name="sadf" value="hello"></property>
<property name="ddd" value="$HJK"></property
```

and I would like to get these:

```
$ABC.D
$DFG.F.G
$HJK
```

I tried many options but without success.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can grep for these values and placeholders and further grep to get the symbol names.

**example**

```
$ grep -o 'value="$.\+"' input.txt | grep -oE '\$(\w|\.)+'
$ABC.D
$DFG.F.G
$HJK
```

note: assumes there is only one placeholder value per line

---

**details**

> - o flag only prints the matches to the pattern
> - E flag for extended regex used to match either word or .

Comment: Thank you! And what about when there is a line: <property name="sdfasdf" value="$ABC.D"></property>   I'd like to get $ABC.D in this case.

Comment: Nice job! Thank you for your help.

Comment: For universal purpose is better use grep -o "$.\+" input.txt | grep -oE '\$(\w|\.)+'

Comment: depends on your context. for example if there were dollar characters in the name attribute then this would return them also whereas explicitly specifying value in the grep match avoids this possible issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **sed**:

```
sed -n 's/.*value="\($[\.a-zA-Z]*\)".*/\1/p' ./input.txt
```

where *input.txt* file contains your text.

Here we use a substitution group to only print the actual match (not the entire matching line).

Comment: Thank you but It will not work when there is <property name="sadf" value="hello"></property> line in file.

Comment: Ah! Now I see: you want to exclude the entries without the dollar sign... Ok, updated. By the way, I updated my answer to deal with your additional input lines containing the dots...

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -nr 's%(\$[A-Za-z][A-Za-z.]*)%\n\1\n%gp' test | grep '^\$[A-Za-z][A-Za-z.]*'
```

This is universal method to find placeholders, independent of whether or not there is only one placeholder per each line and whether or not there is "value=" context near it. All placeholders will be printed on STDOUT.